# check if FILE* is stdout; portable?

Tags: c, stdout, portability

I am currently writing a piece of code whose intended usage is this:

```
program input.txt output.txt
```

or

```
program input.txt
```

in which case it defaults to `stdout`.

This is the code I have now (within `main()`):

```
FILE *outFile;
if (argc < 3) {
        outFile = stdout;
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Will output to file %s\n", argv[2]);
        outFile = fopen(argv[2], "w");
        if (outFile == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERR: Could not open file %s. Defaulting to stdout\n", argv[2]);
            outFile = stdout;
        }
    }
/* ... write stuff to outFile... */
if (argc < 3 && outFile != stdout) {
        fclose(outFile);
    }
```

These are my concerns: first of all, will this successfully open and close outFile when provided? Also, will this successfully *not* close stdout? Can anything bad happen if I close stdout?

Also, is this portable? I compile with `gcc` but this project will be evaluated by a professor using Windows.

Apologies if this is a bit of a mess of a question. I come from Python and am not a CS major (I'm studying mathematics).

Comment: Procedurally code could use a more obvious `FILE *outFile = stdout; if (argc >= 3) { ... } if (outFile && outFile != stdout) { fclose(outFile); }`

Comment: @Clifford Yes - missed the 5 minute window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any program that writes significant data to `stdout`, you *should* close `stdout` immediately before exiting, so that you can check for and report delayed write errors.    (Delayed write errors are a design mistake; it ought to be impossible for `fclose` or `close` to fail.  But we are stuck with them.)

The usual construct is, at the very end of `main`,

```
if (ferror(stdout) || fclose(stdout)) {
    perror("stdout: write error");
    return 1;
}
return 0;
```

Some programs stick an `fflush` in there too, but ISO C requires `fclose` to perform a `fflush`, so it *shouldn't* be necessary.  This construct is entirely portable.

It's important for this to be the very last thing you do before exiting.  It is relatively common for libraries to assume that `stdout` is never closed, so they may malfunction if you call into them after closing `stdout`.  `stdin` and `stderr` are also troublesome that way, but I've yet to encounter a situation where one *wanted* to close those.

It does sometimes happen that you want to close `stdout` before your program is completely done.  In that case you should actually leave the `FILE` open but close the underlying "file descriptor" and replace it with a dummy.

```
int rfd = open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
if (rfd == -1) perror_exit("/dev/null");
if (fflush(stdout) || close(1)) perror_exit("stdout: write error");
dup2(rfd, 1);
close(rfd);
```

This construct is NOT portable to Windows.  There is an equivalent, but I don't know what it is.  It's also not thread-safe: another thread could call `open` in between the `close` and `dup2` operations and be assigned fd 1, or it could attempt to write something to `stdout` in that window and get a spurious write error.  For thread safety you have to duplicate the old fd 1 and close it via that handle:

```
// These allocate new fds, which can always fail, e.g. because
// the program already has too many files open.
int new_stdout = open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
if (new_stdout == -1) perror_exit("/dev/null");
int old_stdout = dup(1);
if (old_stdout == -1) perror_exit("dup(1)");

flockfile(stdout);
if (fflush(stdout)) perror_exit("stdout: write error");
dup2 (new_stdout, 1); // cannot fail, atomically replaces fd 1
funlockfile(stdout);

// this close may receive delayed write errors from previous writes
// to stdout
if (close (old_stdout)) perror_exit("stdout: write error");

// this close cannot fail, because it only drops an alternative
// reference to the open file description now installed as fd 1
close (new_stdout);
```

Order of operations is critical: the `open`, `dup` and `fflush` calls must happen before the `dup2` call, both `close` calls must happen after the `dup2` call, and stdout must be locked from before the `fflush` call until after the `dup2` call.

Additional possible complications, dealing with which is left as an exercise:

- Cleaning up temporary fds and locks on error, when you don't want to stop the whole program on error
- If the thread might be canceled mid-operation
- If a concurrent thread might call `fork` and `execve` mid-operation

Comment: Your first code doesn't close the file if there was an error, what is the rationale there?

Comment: @M.M If there was already a write error, one needs to report _that_, but reporting subsequent errors (if any) is not useful -- what's the user going to do differently for two write errors than they would for one?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's portable and it's okay.

Comment: Thank you. I was especially concerned with directly comparing `outFile` and `stdout`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's portable. You assigned `outfile = stdout`, so they will be equal as long as you don't reassign either of them elsewhere in the program.

You don't really need the `argc < 3` test as well -- the two conditions should always be the same, since you only do the assignment when that's true.

Comment: imho it's penny ante nuance indeed in this case. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/201896/what-is-short-circuiting-in-c-like-languages, however, in programming concept `NULL` checking is done at first most generally

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando you do not need null check in this code. If `fopen` fails, `outfile` will point to `stdout`, so null check is not necessary.

Comment: @snr ` in programming concept NULL checking is done at first` - do you have any proof to substantiate this claim?

Comment: @SergeyA Didn't notice that he did that. Defaulting to stdout when the named file can't be opened is a very unusual thing.

Comment: Actually, I'd probably write something like `if (outfile && outfile != stdout)`

Comment: `outfile` cannot be null at that point so it is redundant to check for it

Comment: @M.M I know, that's why I removed that from my answer. I didn't realize at the time that he defaulted it to `stdout` when `fopen()` fails.